# Preciso recuperar o titulo do campo selecionado em jquery!

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css3

Por exemplo ao clicar na td 'Silva', exiba o titulo "Sobrenome"

```
<pre>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class='title'>Nome</th>
    <th class='title'>Sobrenome</th>
    <th class='title'>Idade</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='campo'>Carlos</td>
    <td class='campo'>Borges</td>
    <td class='campo'>50</td>
  </tr> <tr>
    <td class='campo'>Joao</td>
    <td class='campo'>Silva</td>
    <td class='campo'>22</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</pre>
```

Comment: Poste parte do código que poderemos ajudar com mais facilidade e deixar mais claro a explicação.

Comment: Você não informou dados suficientes para respondermos a sua pergunta.

Comment: é a 1a vez q uso o stack gente, sou iniciante na area, o codigo ainda nao tenho, so esse problema q preciso resolver.

Comment: ja editei, se alguem puder ajudar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue um exemplo utilizando JQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('td').click(function() {
    var titulo = $(this).closest('table').find('th').eq($(this).index()).text();
    alert(titulo);
  });
});
```

```css
pre {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 10px;
  border-collapse: separate;
  min-width: 50px;
}

th {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class='title'>Nome</th>
    <th class='title'>Sobrenome</th>
    <th class='title'>Idade</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='campo'>Carlos</td>
    <td class='campo'>Borges</td>
    <td class='campo'>50</td>
  </tr> <tr>
    <td class='campo'>Joao</td>
    <td class='campo'>Silva</td>
    <td class='campo'>22</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</pre>
```

Comment: mtto bom, vlw Leandro

Comment: Se resolveu, por favor marque como resposta.